# What is this mechanism on my door jamb called?

Tags: doors, lock, door-frame

What is this  mechanism  on my door jamb called?

It’s screwed to the door frame where a striker plate would be, and acts like one, except the black plastic part retracts instead of the striker on the door.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you removed it to see if there are any wires attached to the back side? Is there a corresponding part on the door that interfaces with it or just the normal door handle? **More info** may help, will the door pull open without turning the handle?

Comment: No wires attached to the back, and there’s just a normal door handle on the corresponding part of the door. Once the door is closed the black plastic part doesn’t retract again: you have to turn the handle to open the door. The doors have automatic closing mechanisms, so I assume the function is to reduce wear on the strikers caused by repeated closing.

Comment: Sure does look like an electric latch...

Comment: @Macrod: yes, it looks like a low-friction latching strike. Inside is a pawl that locks it on the pull and glides back on the return.